# Gradle Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Estoy usando Android Studio para un trabajo haciendo una aplicación, y hasta ahora usababa la version 3.4. El problema es que me han colgado un pequeño proyecto que tengo que bajar y usar pero está hecho en la versión 3.5, por lo que he tenido que actualizar.
El problema es que ahora con cualquier proyecto que creo me sale este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a ejecutar alguno de los comandos que indica en vm options pero sigue igual...
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Muestra tu:  build.gradle<module>  y build.gradle <Project>  para poder ver como tienes las configuraciones.

Comment: Hola Santiago, parece que solo era que no captaba bien la carpeta de Android, copiándolo a otra se ha modificado el path del SDK i ya funciona... extraño por eso.

Comment: Eso sucede a veces el cache mantiene la configuraciones anteriores,me alegro que se haya arreglado, Saludos.